# add a button beside each of every row of the table using python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

what I want to do is adding the button beside each of every row of the table using python tkinter. I have this code :

for record in records:

```
button2 = tk.Button(master=wr2, text="delete", bg="red", fg="white", width=3,
height=1, command = lambda record=record: on_click(str(record[0])))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(record, ????))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed widgets inside of a treeview widget.

That being said, you can create an image that looks like a button, and embed the image in the treeview. You can then set up bindings that will react to a click on the image.